# Refreshing an Arbitrarily Deep UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am wondering if there is a good, general paradigm for setting up the refresh action in an arbitrarily deep UITableView. I'm speaking specifically of the refreshControl property of UITableViewController.

One layer is pretty easy and obvious since you just refresh your model and then call [self.tableView reloadData], but even two layers things start conflicting with my notions of good OO programming.

So if the user pulls the table view down to refresh from an arbitrarily deep table, it strikes me that it does absolutely no good to just reload the data from the parent view (which doing, it seems to me, isn't a good OO setup since a child controller isn't supposed to be able to talk directly to the parent). The refresh call needs to be passed back up through the UITableViewControllers until either the top, or some point that would conceivably be the deepest point where the model might have changed, and then push the new, refreshed, data back down through the child UITableViewControllers until it reaches the controller which originated the refresh (checking that that path even still exists at each jump).

The only way I'm coming up with doing this is to have a property in each controller called parentView which is set during prepareForSegue and a method called something like dataForChildView.

```
-(IBAction)refreshTableView {
    [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];
    //self.parentView would be nil at the topmost TVC
    if (self.parentView) {
        [self.parentView refreshTableView];
        self.data = [self.parentView dataForChildView];
    }
    //refresh data
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```

But this seems to me to violate the basic rules of nested controllers, for the reasons I state above.

I haven't yet learned about NSNotifications, but this strikes me as a possible approach. However, since I'm finding nothing online about this question, I wanted to ask before I commit a bunch of time to figuring out if NSNotifications will let me do this. Or maybe I'm missing some even simpler approach.

Edit: the assignment that this is for is set up such that only the topmost UITableViewController has access to data from the model; all lower controllers are passed their data in prepareForSegue. I am starting to think that perhaps this is the problem; there needs to be a model that can be accessed from any level down in the UITableView. Would that be correct?

Answer (score 0):

You could for example refresh your model (which can be passed along to the view controllers) and reload the table views on `viewWillAppear`.

Also the way with notifications you mentioned will work.
Register for notifications in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(selectorThatReloadsTheTableView:) 
                                             name:@"NameOfYourNotification"
                                           object:nil];
```

Don't forget to remote your view controller from the notification center by calling

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Now all you need to do is post the notification once the user pulls-to-refresh:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TestNotification" 
                                                    object:nil];
```

Comment: I forgot one important detail: only the topmost UITableViewController has access to the model's data in the setup the assignment gave. Lower level controllers' data is passed to them during prepareForSegue.

Comment: Then I guess the way to go are indeed notifications or some public refresh method on the root view controller which you can access via the [viewControllers property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/viewControllers) of your UINavigationController.